# Error 100: Unable to render instance groups for deployment

Tags: cloud-foundry, cloudfoundry-uaa, cf-bosh, bosh-deployer

I am deploying Cloud Foundry using bosh. I have completed following things:

1. Spinning up Director VM
2. Setting up bosh target
3. Creating Manifest Stub
4. Uploading bosh release

Currently I am stuck at bosh deploy.

[image: Bosh Release]

```
ubuntu@bosh:~/my-bosh/cf-release$ bosh deploy

Acting as user 'admin' on deployment 'dev' on 'my-bosh'
Getting deployment properties from director...

Detecting deployment changes
.
Cloud Foundry Manifest!! (redacted)
.


Please review all changes carefully
Deploying
---------
Are you sure you want to deploy? (type 'yes' to continue): yes

Director task 44
Deprecation: Ignoring cloud config. Manifest contains 'networks' section.

  Started preparing deployment > Preparing deployment. Done (00:00:01)

Error 100: Unable to render instance groups for deployment. Errors are:
   - Unable to render jobs for instance group 'doppler_z1'. Errors are:
     - Unable to render templates for job 'doppler'. Errors are:
       - Error filling in template 'doppler.crt.erb' (line 1: Can't find property '["loggregator.tls.doppler.cert"]')
       - Error filling in template 'doppler.key.erb' (line 1: Can't find property '["loggregator.tls.doppler.key"]')
   - Unable to render jobs for instance group 'loggregator_trafficcontroller_z1'. Errors are:
     - Unable to render templates for job 'loggregator_trafficcontroller'. Errors are:
       - Error filling in template 'trafficcontroller.crt.erb' (line 1: Can't find property '["loggregator.tls.trafficcontroller.cert"]')
       - Error filling in template 'trafficcontroller.key.erb' (line 1: Can't find property '["loggregator.tls.trafficcontroller.key"]')

Task 44 error
```

Comment: By the way i am deploying cloud foundry on openstack.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your stub is missing certificates for the loggregator certs which are provided by default in the AWS stub (see the 
[minimal-aws.yml](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-release/blob/v250/example_manifests/minimal-aws.yml)).

Also a current [ticket][3] is opened tracking your problem.

Comment: I checked it in my  manifest stub, I had this issue opened in github as well. https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-release/issues/1138 I am able to resolve this issue by adding certificates in manifest.